# Send value to next page with AJAX

Tags: ajax

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('test.php?id1=<?php echo $row['id']; ?> ', 'newwindow', 'width=5000, height=5000'); return false;" ><img src="images/arrowUpDown.png"/></a>
```

I have the above code, is there anyway to send the id to test.php with ajax instead of in the link itself with get?

This is probally easy if you know AJAX. But it's basically my first time.

Comment: you could use jQuery. The ajax method is easy to use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: What is supposed to happen when it gets sent to test.php with ajax?

Comment: It gets used to update an database when u select a different ID.